# A nice version for Vec<Vec<T>>.get?

Tags: rust

Is there any comfortable way to get value from `Vec<Vec<T>>`? I can do it for a normal 1D `Vec`: `vec.get()`, but if `vec` is `Vec<Vec>`, get returns the `Some<Vec<T>>`, not the value of `T`. Is there a nice way to 'get' value from 2D matrix (`Vec<Vec<T>>`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Option::and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.and_then) lets you chain optional return values (`o.and_then(f)` is equivalent to `o.map(f).flatten()`):

```rust
vec.get(i).and_then(|v| v.get(j))
```

It also easily extends to higher dimensions:

```rust
vec
    .get(i)
    .and_then(|v| v.get(j))
    .and_then(|v| v.get(k))
    .and_then(|v| v.get(l))
    // and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

@Aplet123 is of course right, that's the way to go and his answer should be marked correct.

But in case you wonder how to make this prettier, you could wrap it in a custom trait for `Vec<Vec<T>>`:

```rust
trait Get2D {
    type Val;
    fn get2d(&self, i: usize, j: usize) -> Option<&Self::Val>;
    fn get2d_mut(&mut self, i: usize, j: usize) -> Option<&mut Self::Val>;
}

impl<T> Get2D for Vec<Vec<T>> {
    type Val = T;

    fn get2d(&self, i: usize, j: usize) -> Option<&T> {
        self.get(i).and_then(|e| e.get(j))
    }

    fn get2d_mut(&mut self, i: usize, j: usize) -> Option<&mut T> {
        self.get_mut(i).and_then(|e| e.get_mut(j))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut data: Vec<Vec<i32>> = vec![vec![1, 2, 3], vec![4, 5, 6]];

    println!("{}", data.get2d(1, 1).unwrap());

    *data.get2d_mut(0, 1).unwrap() = 42;

    println!("{:?}", data);
}
```

```
5
[[1, 42, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```